# Child products in Magento

Tags: child, store-front

I have set all child products to "not visible individually", still all child products are visible on the frontend. How can i fix it.

Magento

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing indexes and flushing cache:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex;
php bin/magento cache:flush;
```